# How to compare two distributions of Coefficients of Variation?

Tags: statistical-significance, coefficient-of-variation

For my master's thesis (machine learning) I am studying the effect of using a certain type of classifier on the stability of feature importance techniques (SHAP & LIME) under different levels of class imbalance. While the details of the study itself are less important, the result of the study are coefficients of variation of the feature importances for each of the observations under study (let's say 200 here). They can be plotted like this:

[image]

In which all data points are a certain coefficient of variation for one observation by using one of the two models used.

My question is now how I can statistically test whether for a certain class imbalance level (e.g. 1%) the distribution of the coefficients of variation lies significantly higher for the orange model compared to the blue model. I thought of a KS test myself, but I was not sure whether this was possible because of the fact that I'm comparing CV's